# Strategies for Minimizing Model Size in R While Maintaining Predictive Ability

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, r-parsnip

In training regression models with the text package in R, the model's size increases with the number of training datapoints, resulting in unnecessarily large model objects. The models are created using the parsnip package with the glmnet engine. R's memory handling system, which prevents data duplication, makes it difficult to distinguish what components/attributes of the model that take up space; for instance: `object_size(model)` shows 700 MB, but `object_size(model$final_recipe)` and `object_size(model$final_model)` are nearly the same at 698 MB respectively, and thus doesn’t show the actual size of the components.

- How can I efficiently identify and remove the memory-heavy components of the model to reduce its size, while maintaining its predictive ability?

Example:

```
object_size(model) # 700Mb
object_size(model$final_recipe) # 698Mb
object_size(model$final_model) # 698Mb
```

When removing the `final_recipe` attribute (just as an example, nothing I would do in practice):

```
model$final_recipe <- NULL
```

The size of the model is still 700Mb:

```
object_size(model) # 700Mb
```

Answer (score 1):

The [butcher package](https://butcher.tidymodels.org/) likely does what you want: You can inspect your fitted model to find out which parts are so big with `butcher::weigh()` and reduce the size of the object without losing the ability to predict with it with `butcher::butcher()`:

```r
library(butcher)
library(lobstr)

our_model <- function() {
  some_junk_in_the_environment <- runif(1e6) # we didn't know about
  lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) 
}

obj_size(our_model())
#> 8.02 MB

small_lm <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) 
obj_size(small_lm)
#> 22.22 kB

big_lm <- our_model()
weigh(big_lm)
#> # A tibble: 25 × 2
#>    object            size
#>    <chr>            <dbl>
#>  1 terms         8.01    
#>  2 qr.qr         0.00666 
#>  3 residuals     0.00286 
#>  4 fitted.values 0.00286 
#>  5 effects       0.0014  
#>  6 coefficients  0.00109 
#>  7 call          0.000728
#>  8 model.mpg     0.000304
#>  9 model.cyl     0.000304
#> 10 model.disp    0.000304
#> # ℹ 15 more rows

butchered_lm <- butcher(big_lm)
obj_size(butchered_lm)
#> 22.74 kB

predict(butchered_lm, mtcars[1:2,])
#>     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag 
#>      22.59951      22.11189
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have previously attempted to use the butcher package, yet it does not work for our models. After running butcher(model), the model size remains the same as the original. Also, when using the weight() function, all components are given the same size of 4.84 Mb, which happens to be the size of the model object itself. Have you encountered or addressed similar issues in your experience with butcher?

Comment: Also, I am aware of what model components that are of relevance. Is there any way to solely extract the information in these components, (without having to cope with the memory allocation in R), and then recombine them into a "reduced" model?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the predictions, you can extract the coefficients as a matrix and predict with a matrix multiplication.  This example shows the result is the same as `predict(model, data)`.

```r
library(glmnet)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loaded glmnet 4.1-7

x <- mtcars[, c("cyl", "wt", "gear")] |> as.matrix()
y <- mtcars$mpg

fit1 <- cv.glmnet(x, y)

# extract coefficients
b <- coef(fit1, "lambda.min")

# compare predictions
data.frame(
  y,
  x,
  pred1 = as.vector(cbind(1, x) %*% b), # predict with matrix multiplication
  pred2 = as.vector(predict(fit1, x, "lambda.min"))
) |> 
  head()
#>                      y cyl    wt gear    pred1    pred2
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6 2.620    4 22.16138 22.16138
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 2.875    4 21.39066 21.39066
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4 2.320    4 25.90130 25.90130
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 3.215    3 20.36304 20.36304
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 3.440    3 16.84980 16.84980
#> Valiant           18.1   6 3.460    3 19.62254 19.62254

# compare sizes
object.size(fit1)
#> 26496 bytes
object.size(b)
#> 1976 bytes
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for introducing a new predictive method. However, the testing dataset doesn't match the training dataset's shape, making matrix multiplication not suitable for this purpose. Are you aware of any other way of using the coefficients?

Comment: The testing data set doesn't need to have the same number of rows for this multiplication method to work, but it does need to have the same number of columns.  You'll notice that this example uses a matrix type for x.